# flash menu preventing site navigation when accessing url with out www

Tags: flash, .htaccess, redirect

Client has a flash navigation menu on his website. When the site is accessed via www.clientsdomain.com the hardcoded links in the flash nav load pages properly. When accessing the website via the url clientsdomain.com the site navigation links can not load the proper pages and instead just redirect the user to the root domain.

I assume this can be fixed with a change to the .htaccess but I do not know how flash handles these links.

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^clientdomain.com [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.clientdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html\ HTTP/ RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ http://clientdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: yeah scraping the flash menu is our other option for the client and creating a different solution would be in his best interest ie search. thanks for the comment i will reconsider

Answer (score 0):

I think the real solution here is to not use a flash for navigation. Is there really no css effect, or jquery plugin that will accomplish the effect? Is it worth alienating search engines, mobile devices, the visually impaired, and the browser-version deficient? Please reconsider.